# Updating millions of Row after Calculation

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am looking for advice on how should I do following:

1. I have a table in SQL server with about 3 -6 Million Records and 51 Columns.
2. only one column needs to be updated after calculating a value from 45 columns data been taken in mathematical calculation.
3. I already have maths done through C#, and I am able to create Datatable out of it [with millions record yes].

Now I want to update them into database with most efficient manner. Options I know are

1. Run update query with every record, as I use loop on data reader to do math and create DataTable.
2. Create A temporary table and use SQLBulkCopy to copy data and later use MERGE statement
3. Though it is very HARD to do, but can try to make Function within SQL to do all math and just run simple update without any condition to update all in once.

I am not sure which method is faster one or better one. Any idea?

**EDIT**: Why I am afraid of using Stored Procedure

1. First I have no idea how i wrote it, I am pretty new to do this. Though maybe it is time to do it now.
2. My Formula is Take one column, apply one forumla on them, along with additional constant value [which is also part of Column name], then take all 45 columns and apply another formula.
3. The resultant will be stored in 46th column.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you get exclusive access to the DB? eg do you have the option of restoring if something goes wrong?

Comment: is the math from other columns of the same table? e.g. For a very simple example `TotalPrice` would simply be `Unitprice * Quantity`? Or is this a calculated result all on its own and needs to be updated across the entire collection?

Comment: The best approach is to let a stored-procedure calculate this column and update the table with a single update query.

Comment: yes I have exclusive acess.

Comment: Definetly direct TSQL without any C# is the best approach. What is difficult in this implementation?

Comment: it depends on some more factors as "how fast do you need it" and "can you do it in the background while the user continue working" and some more questions...

Comment: Yes math is on same table, ...I am not expert to write stored procedure or function :( Learning that right now.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Please see edit for what is difficult on procedure. thanks

Comment: If it's too hard to implement the calculation in SQL, maybe you could execute the C# code from SQL. I found this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19954/Execute-NET-Code-under-SQL-Server-2005

Comment: I must be missing something; what's wrong with simply `BEGIN TRAN T1; UPDATE BigTable SET LastColumn = /* Math */; COMMIT TRAN T1;`?

Comment: @Sumit this is easily implemented in pure TSQL. either via directly using formula in UPDATE (but this could look a little messy) or by implementing a scalar function in pure TSQL, no CLR required.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think Triggers are best solution for my case, I like @YuriyGalanter 's force to use TSQL. Now I am going to use that only, thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a field that contains a calculation from other fields in the database, it is best to make it a calculated field or to maintain it through a trigger so that anytime the data is changed from any source, the calculation is maintained.

Comment: I have Bulk insert in Database, is usually take 45 minutes to insert all record as we read a Binary file to db. Now if I use Trigger I am afraid that it make read slow, second, again for trigger to perform I need to write procedure which I am not sure how to do.

Comment: I like your idea, and learning to do trigger and will use them as my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .net function which can be called directly from sql here is the link how to create one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx. After you created the function run the simple update statement

Comment: It's also my answer. There is a sql query to upload the DLL in SQL Server. Then your method in the dll are available as SQL functions. For sql server < sql2012 it is .NET 2.0 only. It does not work if sql < 2008

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create a [scalar valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596101404-02-12.aspx) in c#, and call it in as part of a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

Comment: Do I need to add some SDK, in my Visual studio 2013 I didn't see option for Database Project ...